# jquery.browser giving false positives

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I want to exclude some code from browsers earlier than ie8, but I am failing at the first hurdle.

at present, my code should only detect if it is IE at all, but it doesn't

```
$.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {
            if (i!='msie'){
                notIE = true;

            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say better use [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of sniffing the agent (*does not smell good*)..

In regard to the actual question, better use the `jQuery.browser.msie` and `jQuery.browser.version` directly

Answer (score 0):

Documentation about this said that I'll be preferable to use navigator.userAgent.

Take this in consideration ;)
[link text](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html.  You can use a conditional comment to set an IE variable if it is IE.  This is really the only way I've found to guarantee that a browser is IE and what version.

Also, people these days are tending to go away from detecting the browser to detecting features.